# How to login to Dotnetnuke programatically

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-8

I'm developing a mobile app with DotNetNuke 8.0 on the backend.  I can't simply display a DNN login page, so I have to construct the HTTP multipart form for users to log in.  I've researched for hours and can't find a solution.

Comment: Can you explain a little more on the mobile app?  What technology is the mobile app written in and what have you tried for the login?  Is your mobile app responsible for the login which will then redirect to the DNN8 website in a mobile browser?

Comment: The app is written for Apple's iOS in Swift 3.  When a user logs in, I can track anything that user does and provide context for that user.  I have tried to use Apple's WKWebview component.  I can present the html login screen to the user.  When the user successfully logs in, I need to capture the userID.

Comment: I don't want to post an official answer because I don't have a fully vetted answer.  But I think you need to create some kind of handler or service on the DNN site for your mobile app that will perform the AuthenticationLoginBase.OnUserAuthenticated event which will create the login cookie and session.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you mean, but there is a `UserLogin` method in `DotNetNuke.Entities.Users.UserController`.

```
public static void UserLogin(int portalId, UserInfo user, string portalName, string ip, bool createPersistentCookie);
```